# I need ASCII code for F1 - F12 function keys. How can I store function keys action in excel sheet's cell?

Tags: excel, windows-7, vba

I need ASCII code for <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> function keys. How can I store function keys action in excel sheet's cell?

I need to use the function keys function by referring in excel cell to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great to describe your needs in more details. Why do you need to store function keys? I don't think that there are ASCII codes for function keys but you can probably use `sendkeys` and `onkey`. This allows to send and capture the "<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F15</kbd>" key press command.
Please see:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win012.htm

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff197461.aspx

Comment: That was very useful.. :)